# Do bots run code in React's ComponentDidMount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-analytics, google-search

I would like to know if bots (e.g. Google search engine crawlers) run a client side JavaScript and hence can trigger `ComponentDidMount`.

My app has many profiles, and is recording the number of profile views by making a POST request in the profile components' `ComponentDidMount`

e.g.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const { params: { id } } = this.props;
        client.post(`/profile/${id}/views`)
         .catch(err => console.log('Error while incrementing view', err));
    }
    ....
}
```

But I noticed that the number of views I recorded is greater than page views in Google Analytics  by about 30%.

My app is server-side rendered and does not have `<meta name="fragment" content="!>` in the `<head />`.

Could the disparity have been caused by bots running client side javascript, and hence running `ComponentDidMount` code? If so, what would be a reliable way to measure the profile views?

### Edit

I did an experiment to detect bots and check if they are doing a POST request to the URL given above. If so, it means that they are running `ComponentDidMount`.

I put the following middleware in my Express server:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const ua = req.headers['user-agent'];
  if (isBot(ua)) {
    console.log('BOT DETECTED', req.url, ua);
  } else {
    console.log('not a bot', req.url, ua);
  }
  next();
});
```

When a bot hits the profile page, the log shows:

```
BOT DETECTED /profile/1111 Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
```

When I, as a user, hit the profile page, the log shows:

```
not a bot /profile/1111 Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
not a bot /profile/1111/views/views Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.116 Safari/537.36
```

So it seems that Google crawlers do not run my `componentDidMount` code.

But what caused the disparity? Could it have been that Google Analytics page views is not at all accurate?

Comment: search bots don't run javascript - although, it's been many years since I did research myself into the subject, things may have changed since the 00's :D

Comment: Google bots can run JS now, i have insights in this,will answer in 15-20 mins, away from laptop

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja Would you care to share your insights about this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google crawlers now read javascript, so your front end frameworks and libraries work amazingly well. BUT, the things are not really that simple.

Google bots do parse your dynamic content, but if you call any API's(get/post) from your javascript bots generally dont wait for them, thus if most of your content is coming through API calls bot wont read the text.

Now coming to google analytics, yes componentDidMount() is read by google crawlers. I would suggest firing an event as first thing in your `componentDidMount()` before the API call starts.

Comment: It seems that Google crawlers do not run `componentDidMount()`. Could you see my edit and tell me your opinion on what might be the cause of issue?

Comment: can you put a normal print statement in your ```componentDidMount()``` ?  Bots dont work really well with ajax calls

Comment: I don't think I can debug by putting console.log in `componentDidMount()` because when a bot runs that console.log, I have no way of knowing if that happened.

Comment: I just added a guard clause on backend that prevents incrementing the view if the `user-agent` appears to be a bot.